# Gradle 0.9.+/0.9.2 error: Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, maven-central

This morning, all **Android Studio** projects started failing Gradle sync/build/clean with:

> ```
> > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
> ```

The stacktrace looks like:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':Project'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:177)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:507)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_5mm5fv0emagtc49feqskf025g1.run(/projectdir/build.gradle:9)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/builder/testing/api/DeviceProvider
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.$getStaticMetaClass(AppPlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.<init>(BasePlugin.groovy:1908)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.<init>(AppPlugin.groovy:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:67)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider
    ... 71 more
```

There's a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67693) with a fair bit of activity, but no resolution yet.

This is **Android Studio 0.5.2**, gradle version **1.11/0.9.2**.

Ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same error :/ I submitted my issue u.u

Comment: You really need to edit the title to specify 1.11 though, otherwise it makes you sound like an "enterprise" dude bitching about a pre-historic version not working.

Answer (score 50):

Per the latest in the bug report, the issue was that version 0.9.2 was being served from Maven central even though all the necessary components weren't yet available (and gradle doesn't register that as a problem).  This breaks things because pieces are missing.  Version 0.9.2 is **now** completely available and works, but if you're seeing this bug your gradle cache is corrupted.

To fix:

```
gradle --refresh-dependencies
```

or delete

```
~/.gradle/caches
```

and then re-sync.

---

**Prior fix, see above for update.**

Based on comments in [the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67693), it appears that [version 0.9.2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.android.tools.build%7Cgradle%7C0.9.2%7Cjar) is the source of this problem.

To fix, **peg the gradle version to known-good version `0.9.1`** instead of `0.9.+`, `0.+`, `+`, etc.

In your `build.gradle` file, change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1'
```

Comment: I would recommend 0.9.1; it has important bugfixes. 0.9.2 appears to be the bad release.

Comment: Wow, it seems that everyone is getting this bug at the same time :)

Comment: Yup. Was doing a few pull requests and then all of a sudden Travis broke!

Comment: I'm new to android studio, in what file do I have to change this?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco `build.gradle`

Comment: Of course, this would happen for every Android dev on earth at the exact moment I'm trying to configure a new Build Server environment for the 1st time! I thought my Bamboo stuff was broken... Nope, just all of Android \*\*sigh\*\*

Comment: I'm on OS X and I'm assuming ./gradlew --cache rebuild is the equivalent command, but this still produces the same "Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'" error.  Also, I see no 'caches' folder in my .gradle folder.  Should I just use the original fix and hardcode '0.9.1' to replace '0.9.+' in the gradle.build file?

Comment: After almost 2 hours struggling with this issue deleting the caches dir (~/.gradle/caches) and changing the classpath to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1' (instead of '0.9.+') did the trick for me. Thank you so much @blahdiblah

Comment: @JasonHartley The cache is in your home directory .gradle folder, not the project .gradle folder.  Is that the problem?

Comment: `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` did the trick!  Thanks again, @blahdiblah.

Comment: @blahdiblah sorry i am new to android studio but where do i type this command gradle --refresh-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the latest Gradle version 0.9.+, you have to update `gradlewrapper.properties` file too.

Open `gradlewrapper.properties` file which locate under `youProjectPath/gradle/wrapper/gradlewrapper.properties` path:

change `distributionUrl` url From

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

To

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

After that, I changed build.gradle dependencies to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

and synced gradle files and everything when good.

Cheers