# Android Studio 5.2 - refresh failed. Cause:com.google.common.collect.Maps

Tags: android, android-studio

Just out of nowhere got this issue on every project in **Android Studio 5.2**

```
Gradle 'MyApplication4' project refresh failed:
        Cause: com.google.common.collect.Maps
        Gradle settings
```

Can really find any infomation about it so will make a check here before reinstall

Comment: Could you be hitting this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670395/gradle-error-unable-to-load-class-com-android-builder-testing-api-deviceprovid

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'` in your build.gradle to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1'` it should fix it. 
The new release 0.9.2 breaks something.

Comment: Confirmed correct fix, someone on Google quarters pressed the wrong button apparently.

Comment: Per [the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67693) the issue isn't 0.9.2 per se, it's that it became available from Maven Central piecemeal corrupting people's gradle caches because they only got some of the files.  The fix is to rebuild the cache now that it's fully available: `gradle --rebuild cache`.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting $HOME/.gradle/caches directory and then rebuilding works (It may be required to restart Android Studio.).

Comment: .. and after delete, restart android studio, at least i had to!