# Android Studio Gradle 'HelloWorld' project refresh failed

Tags: android, gradle

I created my 1st project in Android Studio and named it "**HelloWorld**" and when I start my project I get an error which says,

***Gradle 'HelloWorld' project refresh failed***

***Error:Cause: com/google/common/collect/MapMaker$RemovalCause***

and the project window stops processing, and it doesn't make **HelloWorld C:/HelloWorld folder** as **app**.
Any way to fix this please? **[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/818Bb.png)**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the IDE logs? You selected the "map example" from the getting started?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 5.2 - refresh failed. Cause:com.google.common.collect.Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670444/android-studio-5-2-refresh-failed-causecom-google-common-collect-maps)