# Android Studio issue when starting

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started **Android Studio** and I got this:

```
WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter -  
2014-03-26 13:58:00,447 [  21456]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectImporter - 
Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider'.
```

Functionality like editing and debugging won't work.

I updated **Android Studio** and I got a different problem when starting, but it fixed itself.

Comment: Related? [Gradle error: Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22670395)

Comment: Yes it seems it is a duplicate.