# Failed to refresh Gradle project: Cause: com.google.common.collect.Maps

Tags: android, android-studio

For some reason Android Studio gives me an error:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project: Cause: com.google.common.collect.Maps

gradlew --stacktrace:
...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.Map
...
```

How to fix this?

Comment: It is not duplicate: 1. Gradle 0.9.+/0.9.2 error: Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider' answer was not accepted! 2. My fix is to remove .gradle dir and set maven central repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is similar to the other one about an update to android studio 5.2....
see solution at 
[Gradle 0.9.+/0.9.2 error: Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670395/gradle-0-9-0-9-2-error-unable-to-load-class-com-android-builder-testing-api)

Comment: I know you cannot comment yet with 1 rep, but this should really be a comment rather than an answer ;).

Comment: It is not duplicate:
1. Gradle 0.9.+/0.9.2 error: Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider' answer was not accepted!

2. My fix is to remove .gradle dir and set maven central repo.