# Android studio gradle issues, Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This error just arrived, it have been working to sync and build and now just cant build anymore or sync gradle?

I have already tried to clean build by click build -> clean build no didnt work either? Relaly annoying now!!

```
* Where:
```

Build file '/home/mikaeljohansson/AndroidStudioProjects/myproj/build.gradle' line: 5

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproj'.

  > Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container.

Here is the other gradle.build files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
}
```

Here is the other on global one

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438375/android-studio-gradle-errors-content-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: Post your build log here.

Comment: I had this when I used non-UTF8 chars in code

Comment: Ok gradle files added, i cant run gradle clean

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: Where can i see that?

Comment: Gradle 2.4 i think, but how can this just not working anymore, for 100 hoursit wrorked fine then not anymore ??

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by remove maps under res catalog structure!