# android 0.5.9 gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, synchronization

I have an Android university project. I have installed Android studio 0.5.9 a few days ago, but I keep getting the **"gradle sync failed" error: Protocol Family Unavailable**. I have tried everything on the internet, but nothing works. Please help

P.S It never worked, I am not trying to import an existing project, I create a new one, than the gradle thing happens

Comment: What is your gradle version? have you tried updating it?

Comment: it's gradle 1-10. it installed with android studio and it says that it has the latest updates

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670395/gradle-0-9-0-9-2-error-unable-to-load-class-com-android-builder-testing-api) answer?

Comment: I tried changing classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+' in gradle.build but still nothing. I have also deleted the entire .gradle folder, still nothing.  "To fix:

gradle --refresh-dependencies" I don't know how to do that or where to write it.