# Error while trying to make .apk file

Tags: android

When upload the app to the device via USB debug mode i dont have problem, the app can compile.  In the other hand when i try to do the .apk file  i got the next error, help!

P.D: Sorry for my english

Image error [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hnDD8o_C5dUmlReUQ5eUZvVFk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438375/android-studio-gradle-errors-content-not-allowed-in-prolog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Opiatefuchs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1538986/opiatefuchs) referenced, you would need to clear your gradle cache by `gradle clean --refresh-dependencies`. Alternatively, you could delete the contents of the `~/.gradle/caches` directory, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670684/4230345) answer.